# Should I use 'leitmotifs', the plural of leitmotif, in academic English?

Tags: word-choice, differences, grammatical-number, loanwords

Should I, in an scientific book, use the word 'leitmotifs', the plural of leitmotif?
Some dictionaries seem to know it in the plural form, but does it sound very weird or massively pretentious to the native ear?

Using 'themes' may be an alternative, but is sounds a bit generic to me.

Comment: Dictionaries don't normally list regular plurals unless there's there's some significant usage difference *other* than that implied by "more than one". So it's not that only some dictionaries "seem to know" the plural - it's just that most see no reason to list a perfectly ordinary plural form that has no special extra meaning that doesn't naturally follow from the singular as defined. If you like the word *leitmotif* and you're confident your readers will understand what you mean, there's no reason to avoid it just because your context requires a plural form (but it's "arty", not scientific).

Comment: Merriam-Webster gives two forms for the word in question: _leitmotif_ (the more common) and _leitmotiv_ (the less). By neither identifying the term as a collective noun nor including plural forms in the entry, MW signals that the plural spellings are _leitmotifs_ and _leitmotivs_. It seems to me that the plural _leitmotifs_ is appropriate in any literary setting where the singular _leitmotif_ would be.

Comment: "Leitmotifs" is only one letter more pretentious than "leitmotif".

Comment: Don't use *leitmotivs*. It looks strange to me, and nobody will know how to pronounce it (*leitmotiv* spelled with a "v" should still end with an /f/ sound). Also, it might confuse people who know German, where the plural of *Leitmotiv* (with an /f/ sound) is *Leitmotive* (with a /v/ sound). But *leitmotif* is the anglicized form, and the English plural *leitmotifs* works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I decided to use 'recurring themes' instead.  Leitmotifs should have confused me right away, as I actually am German :)

Comment: @PeterShor: I don't know why MW doesn't list _leitmotive_ as a variant plural of _leitmotiv_. The [Ngram graph and Google Books results](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leitmotiv%2Cleitmotive%2Cleitmotivs&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=0&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleitmotiv%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleitmotive%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleitmotivs%3B%2Cc0) for _leitmotiv/leitmotive/leitmotivs_ for 1900–2008 show considerable support in English for _leitmotive_ as a plural, though some matches involve German texts or use _leitmotive_ as a singular variant of _leitmotif_.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong ... Leitmotive is pronounced with an /f/ sound. I must not understand the rules for when German fricatives get voiced.

Comment: @PeterShor: There isn't intervocalic voicing in general for German fricatives. The letter "v" can represent /v/ in some words, and /f/ in others. At the end of a word, it always represents /f/, since /v/ is not possible there. When it comes before a native German grammatical ending, there doesn't seem to be any main tendency: *nerven* prescriptively has /f/, the speakers [here](https://www.howtopronounce.com/german/motive/) have /v/ in *motive*...

Comment: ...(and [this](https://books.google.com/books?id=Emhy4xKDyFkC&pg=PA19&lpg=PA19&dq=motiv+german+pronunciation&source=bl&ots=G5lp6B7CEf&sig=dVCWxU3Brh--c1EIq55iMZGom5c&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjL2ZfLzrzKAhVC9WMKHd5ZBcE4ChDoAQgwMAQ#v=onepage&q=motiv%20german%20pronunciation&f=false) describes *motiv* as having underlying but devoiced /v/ ) and *brave* apparently has /v/ (although *brav* has /f/ of course).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term *leitmotif* is almost exclusively used in the context of music, but sometimes literature as well. Whether you use the singular form or plural form is irrelevant as long as you use it correctly.

An alternate spelling is *leitmotiv*, plural *leitmotivs*.

The two spellings seem to be fairly equally popular until around 1960, when the spelling *leitmotif* started becoming much more common. (Source: [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=leitmotif%2C%20leitmotiv&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cleitmotif%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleitmotiv%3B%2Cc0))

So the larger question is this: Who is your audience? And will they understand your use of this term in the context of your discussion?

I question this because of your opening statement, "in an [sic] scientific book". (By the way, "an" there should be "a".) I'm fairly certain this term is not used much in the scientific community, but rather the Arts. That's not to say you *shouldn't* use it; but keep in mind, you may need to couch it in such a way that it's clear what you mean.